# WPF BackgroundWorker while main window loading

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

i have WPF application with main window. i want the BackgroundWorker to open a loading window (WinLoading) while main window is loading and close it while loading is finish. i have this code in main window. when i run it i get the WinLoading window open after the action was finished before the main window is open (after 10 seconds).

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        wLoadingService = new BackgroundWorker();
        wLoadingService.DoWork += wLoadingService_DoWork;
        wLoadingService.RunWorkerCompleted += wLoadingService_RunWorkerCompleted;
        wLoadingService.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        wLoadingService.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        wLoadingService.RunWorkerAsync();

        //some action (takes 10 seconds).....
    }

    void wLoadingService_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            WinLoading.EndDisplay();
        }));
    }

    void wLoadingService_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            WinLoading.Loading("Connecting...");
            WinLoading.BeginDisplay();
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly run the work on the main UI thread using `this.Dispatcher.Invoke`. This effectively renders your background worker useless, forcing it to wait until the main thread is finished with "some action".

"Some action" is the long running task here. *That* is the code you want to execute from your background worker, while your main thread handles the WinLoading dialog.